# Spring Security - Change LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint redirect strategy

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm in need of changing the `DefaultRedirectStrategy` used out of the box by the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

The scenario is when an unauthenticated user navigates a secured URL: I can see from the logs that `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence` is called, and, following the flow, eventually a `DefaultRedirectStrategy` is called. The login URL created for the redirect, however, is not correct because of a reverse proxy (built on `Apache`) sitting in front of the web application.

I already did the same in many spots (for example in the logout success handler, which was doing exactly the same, but it was easy to customize with my own redirect strategy). In this case I can't find an obvious way to tweak the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem: The reverse proxy should be fixing *all* redirect requests generated by the web server, including the login redirect.

Comment: hi @Andreas, do you mean I should have some rewrite rule put in place at reverse proxy layer?

Comment: Yes. Don't you need that anyway for any other redirect sent by the web server?

Comment: ForwardedHeaderFilter may come in handy in this case, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306818/how-to-setup-forwardedheaderfilter-for-login-using-spring-security-without-sprin

Comment: @jzheaux this sounds actualyl ineresting. I currently patched with a filter of my own that basically does the same because I didn't know about the existence of that filter!